# how to remove an array element in array of array in js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to remove an array element from an array of arrays. but i am not able to do it.

JS code:

```
var blueTiles = [];
blueTiles.push([1, 1]);
blueTiles.push([2, 2]);
blueTiles.push([3, 3]);

var removeCoord = [2, 2];

var index = blueTiles.indexOf(removeCoord);
if (index > -1) blueTiles.splice(index, 1);
```

but here i am trying to get position of array element in blueTile array ans remove using splice function.
but i am getting index value as -1 even though [2, 2] exists in it

please help me in solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this as your index (checks all array elements against the remoceCoord elements)

```
var index = blueTiles.findIndex(x=>x.every((y,i)=>y===removeCoord[i]))
```

```js
var blueTiles = [];
blueTiles.push([1, 1]);
blueTiles.push([2, 2]);
blueTiles.push([3, 3]);

var removeCoord = [2, 2];

var index = blueTiles.findIndex(x => x.every((y, i) => y === removeCoord[i]))
if (index > -1) blueTiles.splice(index, 1);

console.log(blueTiles)
```

Comment: thank u for the reply, i am getting some syntax error in this, can you please recheck.

Comment: if you rut the code snippet, you can see that there are no syntax errors,, which error do you get what does it say

Comment: ow sorry, its my mistake i made a typo, thank you Eugen sunic, can you explain me how does it work and why my code dosent.